# What is the best relation for 3 tables, polymorphic or has_many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I am new to rails and I want some help to create the proper associations to fit my requirements. 
I have users, group of users and spreads. User can have his own spreads, on the other hand a user can be part of a group that have it's own spreads for all users part of the group.
I have a doubt if I must use polymorphic association or has_many_through.
I tried this:

User

```
belong to group
has_many :spreads, through :group
```

Group

```
has_many :users
has_many :spreads
```

Spread

```
belong_to :group
```

Comment: The VS premise is nonsensical. Both are tools that solve very different problems. `has_many through:` lets you create many to many associations and indirect associations through another model. Polymorphic associations let you create an association where the target table is dynamic - its a way of cheating the objection relational impedance problem that solves a very real problem in libraries like ActionStorage but comes with a hefty load of problems on its own (no foreign key constraints, bad join support, etc).

Comment: In this case you want to stop thinking that the solution here is one associations. Rather just create two separate associations and two separate join tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableUsersGroups 
rake:db migrate
```

**You can create migrate file.Add table_id and user_id to migrate file.Add a model.Fix to
relationships**

```
 **Spread**
belong_to :group
belong_to :user

**User**
has_many :spreads
has_many :groups, :through => :spreads

**Group** 
has_many :spreads
has_many :users, :through => :spreads
```